# Issues with react-bootstrap-autosuggest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I've literally spent the entire day trying to add this package: https://github.com/affinipay/react-bootstrap-autosuggest to a create-react-app I recently ejected. But, I've been getting the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/react-bootstrap-autosuggest/lib/Autosuggest.js
Module not found: 'Autosuggest.scss' in /Users/Logan/Development/projects/app_name/client/node_modules/react-bootstrap-autosuggest/lib

 @ ./~/react-bootstrap-autosuggest/lib/Autosuggest.js 38:0-27
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
var paths = require('./paths');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    client:
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', ''],
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: [
          /\.html$/,
          /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          /\.css$/,
          /\.json$/,
          /\.svg$/,
          /\.sass$/,
          /\.scss$/
        ],
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
      },
      // Load and compile SCSS
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "css-loader!sass-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      // "file" loader for svg
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      }),
    ];
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "detect-port": "1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "filesize": "3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "gzip-size": "3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.3",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.2",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.5.0",
    "recursive-readdir": "2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "strip-ansi": "3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-bootstrap-autosuggest": "^0.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^4.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.41.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-fa": "^4.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-redux-form": "^1.7.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "superagent": "^3.4.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>[/\\\\](build|docs|node_modules|scripts)[/\\\\]"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to you webpack config:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /Autosuggest\.scss$/,
    'react-bootstrap-autosuggest/src/Autosuggest.scss')
```

Source: https://github.com/affinipay/react-bootstrap-autosuggest/issues/1

Comment: The code above, as well as some additional code from the link you provided, solved my issue. You're my hero!

Comment: Anytime. Whenever you're having an issue with a package like this, their `Issues` page should be your first stop.